# How to calculate minimum set of jars required to compile Play application?

Tags: ant, sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

Our release engineering is dictating that we cannot use SBT. We have to use ANT.

We need a proper list of jars that are required to compile a PlayFramework application.  We are using Play 2.3.4 and (i think!) Scala 2.10 --- this was what got downloaded from activator-1.2.3.

Any thoughts on how to figure out minimum essential set of jars?

Right now, there is an issue with  Controller class and iteratees... (i imagine these are in some scala jars)

Questions:

1. what do the jar numbering scheme on jars in user's ivy cache have two sets of numbers - for eg, play-java-2.3.4-2.10.  Does this mean it's Play framework rev 2.3.4 compiled with scala 2.10 ?
2. is there a minimum list?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** `activator stage` and then grab the jars from `target/universal/stage/lib`.

Play Framework offers `stage` task that can [prepare your application to be run in place](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production#Using-the-stage-task):

> This cleans and compiles your application, retrieves the required
>   dependencies and copies them to the `target/universal/stage` directory.
>   It also creates a `bin/<start>` script where `<start>` is the project’s
>   name. The script runs the Play server on Unix style systems and there
>   is also a corresponding bat file for Windows.

After you've executed the `stage` task, you grab the jars from `target/universal/stage` and you should be fine to go offline or...cough, cough...ant.

```
[jars-needed-play] $ stage
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/jars-needed-play/target/scala-2.11/jars-needed-play_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jars-needed-play/}root...
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/jars-needed-play/target/scala-2.11/jars-needed-play_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/jacek/sandbox/jars-needed-play/target/scala-2.11/api...
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/jars-needed-play/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/jars-needed-play/target/jars-needed-play-1.0-SNAPSHOT-assets.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
model contains 17 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/jars-needed-play/target/scala-2.11/jars-needed-play_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/jars-needed-play/target/scala-2.11/jars-needed-play_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Oct 1, 2014 9:09:29 AM

[jars-needed-play] $ eval "ls target/universal/stage/lib" !
ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.1.1.jar
ch.qos.logback.logback-core-1.1.1.jar
...
xerces.xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
xml-apis.xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
[info] ans: Int = 0
```